# Throwing a baseball on top of a cliff

Tags: calculus, physics

> A baseball is thrown from the stands 32 ft above the field at an angle of 30 degrees up from the horizontal. When and how far away will the ball strike the ground if its initial speed is 32ft/sec?

My attempt:
Vertical $r(t)$ is given as $$32\sin(30^\circ)t - 1/2(gt^2) = -32$$
then I get $$16t - (9.81/2)t^2 = -32$$
which is equivalent to:

$$16t-(9.81/2)t^2 = -32$$

Then do quadratic equation and get $t = 4.66$ sec.

**However, the textbook describes g as 32ft/sec$^2$.** and gives $t = 2$ and distance as 55.4 ft.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All the values are in ft or ft/s. The value of $g$ you're using, however, is in the usual m/s^2. You can't compare values given in different units, and hence have to use the value of $g$ in the correct units - either use 32 ft/s^2, or turn all other distances and speeds into meters and use the normal value.

Comment: Wow, haven't noticed that. Thank you!